# Cloud Run error: File not found (but it's there)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I keep getting file not found error with a docker image on Cloud Run:

```
{
insertId: "64e042dc00012912dc1845f7"
labels: {6}
logName: "projects/vvchatapp-383303/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-08-19T04:19:40.415647981Z"
resource: {2}
textPayload: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './frontend/investpr/dist/index.html'"
timestamp: "2023-08-19T04:19:40.076050Z"
}
```

However the file is in the image when I build the image locally (and it runs without errors on locally build images form the same Dockerfile).

Any ideas what might be the problem or how to debug it in Cloud Run?

Running the same image locally.

Comment: If you use the same image, the behavior should be the same. If you build your image somewhere else, where? How did you upload the files? You can also inspect your container package with dive, a binaries that unpack your container, super usefull!

Comment: the file is part of the image. When build locally (docker on Windows) it works. When build by google-cloud-build (for google-cloud-run) it does not -- cannot find the file.

Comment: So, the problem is not on Cloud Run, it's on Cloud Build. you should not have the file in your path or the file is not uploaded. Do you commit this file in your git repository? Do you have a gitignore that hide this file?

Comment: Good one @guillaumeblaquiere! It was in git and not in gitignore but it was capitalized differently in git (which on Windows doesn't matter and explains the difference). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's that `./frontend/` path that's the problem. In Google Cloud Run you have no control over the working directory. So what is . ? Just use an absolute path like
`/root/path/somewhere/index.html` and then you don't have to worry about the working directory.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It sounded plausible so I tried it but it did not work either. 
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/frontend/investpr/dist/index.html'" 
I tried with a relative path also "frontend/investpr/dist/index.html" -- same result. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: @user22415569 - you designed the app and file layout. Launch your container in Docker, attach to the container, and find the file. Then use the absolution path in your code.

Comment: That's what I did to verify the file is present in the container but this was local Docker. Is there a way to attach to a Cloud Run container?  (I could not find one)

Comment: i think you need to add debug println statements then. like print("got here 1") and print("got here 2" + files) where files is an ls of the directory.  It must be the Container Build Process or the Build Context that isn't copying the file and these print statements will confirm it.